# Adding image in docx table using docx project

Tags: python, image, cell, jpeg, docx

So I'm trying to add a jpg to a docx using docx module.

Here is the code

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if result.status_code == 200:                    
    table.rows[row].cells[2]._element.clear_content()
    with open("image.jpg",'wb') as image:                        
        image.write(result.content)

    table.rows[row].cells[2].add_paragraph().add_run()
    table.rows[row].cells[2].add_paragraph().add_run().add_picture("image.jpg", width=Cm(width))
    #table.rows[row].cells[2].add_paragraph().add_run().add_picture("image.jpg")
    table.rows[row].cells[2].add_paragraph().add_run()
```

Now the weird part.
I have two images that both are 250x250 and with the following [image props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsdGR.jpg)

The left one can be added but the right one no matter what i do it can't be added.
I don't get any error, it just won't add it to the document.
I have other images that are similar and I can't find anything wrong with them.

Comment: It seams it was an issue with the aspect ratio, I fixed it by changing Cm to Pt and also i've converted the jpg to a png with Pillow.